# How to see both sides of a partial class

Tags: .net, winforms, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I am creating a Windows Form and the class is declare as partial. I can code all the behaviors on my side, but I noticed that on the other side of the partial class I can see how the UI is created. How can I open this? (I noticed this hidden code by stepping through in the debugger)

Comment: It's not hidden, just click on the + on the right side of the form cs file in the Solution Explorer and you can see the designer file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can click on the Class name, then press F12, It will list every declaration of your class, either partial or not.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

In your solution explorer expand your form (by clicking the plus sign on the left, it has a .cs extension). In there is a myForm.designer.cs. In that file is the rest of your partial class.